# Apache Tomcat security: User management & log file management

Tags: security, tomcat, logging

I'm trying to monitor Tomcat log files from a security perspective.

My questions are related to two main areas:

1) User Management

- 1.a) Does the Tomcat GUI provide any option to create and delete users, or does this have to be done directly via the tomcat-users.xml file?
- 1.b) Does Tomcat create any log entry when users are being created / deleted?

2) How are log files being handled?

- 2.a) Is there any option provided by the GUI to modify / delete Tomcat log files?
- 2.b) Are modifications in log files being logged in some log file only accessible by root?

The reason I'm asking is that I would like to look for relevant security events in Tomcat logs to establish some kind of monitoring on this. However, the only thing I could find was "Access Logging" for Tomcat, which unfortunately does not answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Very short answers:

**1.a.:** the tomcat gui doesnt provide options to create, modify or delete users

**1.b.:** because of the absence of the corresponding functionality, not any logs are created

**2.a.:** the tomcat gui doesnt provide opstions to modify or delete log files

**2.b.:** because of the absence of the correspondig functionality, not any logs are created

---

the `tomcat-users.xml` is a very slim and lightweight out of the box solution

---

usually developers make use of an identity-management like ldap or they develop and/or implement their own user-administration

Comment: provided some explanation

Comment: Thank you for your precise answers. Since the abovementioned events do not trigger log entries, I wonder if there are best-practices to monitor the catalina.log (or any other) file regarding other security-relevant incidents. I'm thinking about something like "user tried to access .passwd file" etc. for which I could look out in the log files. Are there manuals that give such recommendations about events/log entries to watch in a security monitoring? The two events I mentioned in my initial question seemed to be security-relevant to me, but as they are not logged, I'm looking for alternatives.